# Can a .env file contain build arguments?

Tags: docker, environment-variables

Can a Docker `.env` file contain variables like a `docker-compose.yml` file can?

In other words, can I do `my_variable=${VARIABLE}` in that file, or does it have to be within the `environment` section of the `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Easy way to find out is to try. Did it work?